# Does adjunctum mean an essential feature or attribute?

Tags: meaning

According to [William Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=adjunctum) it does:

> adjunctum, adjuncti  N  N   [XXXCO]   quality, characteristic,
> **essential feature/attribute**; collateral circumstance;

However, I'm wondering if it might be an error because it seems contradictory to speak of something as both collateral and essential.

According to [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=adjunctum&la=la#lexicon), the various definitions of *adjungo* involve the idea of something joined or added to something else, which would be inconsistent with it being essential.

Finally, *adjuncti* in the following sentence was translated with the English word *adjunct*, along with a footnote defining it as "Something added to another thing but not an essential part of it":

> In Scripturis vel promissionibus, enunciationes continent et exhibent
> objectum fidei, vocanturque objectum fidei per metonymiam adjuncti.

After consulting various Latin dictionaries, Whitakers was the only one I found that explicitly mentioned this question concerning it being essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't find Whitaker's definition so surprising. First of all, note that ***at**tribuere* and ***ad**iungere* can be synonymous: e.g., 'to add/adjoin to'. As for your question, *adiuncta* can be interpreted as a characteristic, but not necessarily permanent, set of attributes. Perhaps the existence of examples like the following one motivated the part of Whitaker's entry you find problematic.

> ne forte seniles mandentur iuveni partes pueroque viriles: semper in **adiunctis** aevoque morabitur aptis. ([**Hor. *Ars Poetica*. 176-178**](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/893/6/0/8174-8183,8184-8189@1#0)).

---

EDIT

For further information confirming my view above, please take a look at this [**link**](https://books.google.es/books?id=k4Dcf4d0N7MC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=semper%20%22in%20adiunctis%20aevoque%22&source=bl&ots=X7BodD774C&sig=ACfU3U3z7UYodLanNL8BtAC7ACqx0Kj4mw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzwMC3r6LuAhUpx4UKHVFODiwQ6AEwB3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=semper%20%22in%20adiunctis%20aevoque%22&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

Although I didn't specify in my question, my interest in this has more to do with post-medievel Latin rather than classical.

Concerning classical Latin, both [Charles Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=adiunctus) and [Henry Nettleship](https://books.google.es/books?id=k4Dcf4d0N7MC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=semper%20%22in%20adiunctis%20aevoque%22&source=bl&ots=X7BodD774C&sig=ACfU3U3z7UYodLanNL8BtAC7ACqx0Kj4mw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzwMC3r6LuAhUpx4UKHVFODiwQ6AEwB3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=semper%20%22in%20adiunctis%20aevoque%22&f=false) quote Horace, which is the same quote given in Mitomino's answer. The main idea is *adjuncta aevo*, i.e. qualities which accompany a certain age. Whether that is better defined as an *essential* quality, as defined by Lewis, or a *characteristic* quality, as defined by Nettleship, might be a matter of debate.

However, in later Latin, the meaning seems to have tended toward one which usually (if not always) excludes the essential. Alexander Baumgarten, for example, defines *modi* as predicable accidents or adjuncts:

> Affectiones habent rationem in essentia, §. 41. hinc aut suficientiem,
> aut minus, §. 21,10. Illae sunt ATTRIBUTA hae MODI accidentia
> praedicabilia, s. logica, cf. §. 191 adiuncta, praedicata secundaria.
> (*[Metaphysica](https://korpora.zim.uni-duisburg-essen.de/kant/agb-metaphysica/II1Ba.html#50)*, §50)

Antonius Forti wrote that *adiuncta* are those which are not necessarily joined to something:

> Adiuncta sive Attributa, quae vulgo circunstantiae appelantur, sunt
> ea, quae cum re sunt coniuncta, sed non necessario. (*[Miles rhetoricus
> et poeticus](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=deFoAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22adiuncta%22%20attributa&source=bl&ots=B19rrkoT-f&sig=ACfU3U0u5Jc0V8PV9_7BNMQ65uLZ1RRhuA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG8N3OnKPuAhVE62EKHak6CdQQ6AEwBnoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22adiuncta%22%20attributa&f=false)*)

Johann Heinrich Alsted distinguished adjuncts from essential properties and perfections:

> Proprietates Dei essentiales non disserunt ab essentia nec inter se,
> realiter, sed tantum ratione: & alias dicuntur attributa, adiuncta,
> modi, & perfectiones essentiae divinae, interdum etiam divina nomina;
> nonnunquam affectiones & passiones Dei, non ita bene.
> (*[Theologia naturalis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=fAQ_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22adiuncta%22%20attributa&source=bl&ots=v4c_QlfgpH&sig=ACfU3U11SE5qDaaDyIWKEJLDz4PnaHxM6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG8N3OnKPuAhVE62EKHak6CdQQ6AEwB3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22adiuncta%22%20attributa&f=false)*)